# tcptraceroute is working but telnet got timeout

Tags: unix, telnet

I'm trying to telnet public server using specific interface.

```
# telnet -b 10.144.238.192 google.com 80
Trying 142.251.42.14...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

If I test using tcptraceroute on the same interface it looks fine.

```
# tcptraceroute -i net1 google.com 80
Running:
        traceroute -T -O info -i net1 -p 80 google.com
traceroute to google.com (142.251.42.14), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  182.19.106.105 (182.19.106.105)  5.928 ms  5.891 ms  5.873 ms
 4  74.125.49.176 (74.125.49.176)  7.382 ms  7.040 ms  7.024 ms
 5  172.253.69.227 (172.253.69.227)  6.790 ms 216.239.57.17 (216.239.57.17)  8.752 ms  8.840 ms
 6  209.85.250.139 (209.85.250.139)  6.053 ms 209.85.248.61 (209.85.248.61)  4.767 ms  4.891 ms
 7  bom12s19-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.42.14) <syn,ack>  4.711 ms  4.683 ms  4.537 ms
```

Any idea on what happened?

Comment: Why are you forcing telnet to use a specific interface? Why no just let the system work that out for itself?

Comment: @Bib Actually I'm working on app that communicates with remote server using TCP. The requirement is to be able to select which interface its going to use. The app got timeout only on this particular interface. This doesn't look like my app issue since telnet also got timeout. So I'm just trying to understand what might causing this.